# What is a suitable icon for nonspecific spirituality?

Tags: icon, symbolism

Christianity can be represented with the crucifix icon, Judaism with a Start of David, Bhuddism with a Dharma wheel, etc, etc.

What icon would be suitable to represent spirituality in general, not specifically any faith or religion?

I'm not looking for original art, just struggling to think of a good symbol.

Is there an official symbol or what could be suitable for this?

Comment: Possibly a [flower](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAM33.png) or other "natural" element, like [wind](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgXD0.jpg) or another plant

Comment: that also conveys nature more than spirituality - which involves the human (usually)... i've sent a few interpretations after having spent much of 2021 in comparative spirituality study

Answer (score 3):

I really, really doubt there is an universal symbol because normally a symbol itself needs to include some specifics about the philosophy or content.

But let's try to make one.

I am trying to make it without a specific style. This style can be defined later.

To compare what I mean by style here is a google search about another "sphere" of humans, a "social sphere". Currently, this search is dominated by social networks logos, but you can find some that represent social by using several persons together. https://www.google.com.mx/search?q=social+icon&rlz=1C1GKLA_enMX664MX664&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5kPnY2r_YAhWL8oMKHYEkA8UQ_AUICigB&biw=1920&bih=1012

Here is a couple of rough icons using that idea to define a "style".

[image]

A "spiritual sphere or plane" could complement, let's say a physical or biological plane, emotional plane, intellectual one. So here are some that potentially illustrate those planes.

[image]

And a spiritual plane normally includes some kind of transcendental plane. Some specific philosophies can call it "Illumination", and some others can represent this in some form or another of "light". So we can probably use this as a starting point.

[image]

Depending on the philosophy behind it, this illumination can be from a "soul" based on the heart (E) or more "mind based", in the head (F).

Comment: Some religions, Christianity comes to mind, believe that "illumination" cannot come from the heart or mind but rather from God alone, so this icon, while in the right direction, isn't perfect. Plus lots of things come from the head and heart, so the icons proposed in this answer fail to make a distinction between those other things and spiritual things

Comment: The point is not where this illumination comes from, but the result it produces. The Aaura" on saints paintings is a representation of this. In the Virgen of Guadalupe Image this rays are present. But they do not irradiate from the heart, but from the womb.

Comment: But even in the case this "light" does not come from the person itself it could represent light iluminating the person... from behind. :o)

Comment: this looks more like disco in the elevator than spirituality.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that the circle is the most representative as a spiritual symbol. I believe it symbolizes the ongoing energy found in nature. It is unbroken and unbent, forming unity. It is universal, divine, and sacred to many cultures.

The circle is found in both the male and female symbols. In Chinese culture, it represents "Heaven", as well as being used for the Yin and Yang symbol (balance). Ancient Celtics used the circle to form a ring of protection.

The circle is THE symbol of divinity.

Comment: A circle alone is a circle to me, I would not relate it with spirituality at all as a user

Comment: I also agree on the circle being the most universal... submitted a post that includes some universal poses like sitting meditation, prayer mudra etc and the circle

Answer (score 0):

You are not going to get a definitive. I created this avatar about 20 years ago based on research concerning the earliest examples of iconography and the simplest symbols available, a line, circle and a triangle - I agree with @GISjaclyn about the circle representing divinity. The equilateral triangle represents purpose, composition, a deliberate construction. Together with the line as a central core they form life which is what I believe GOD to be. Visually it could be taken as symbolising a person, humankind, one creed (no religion, colour or sexuality) It's a personal interpretation - not how stack requires answers but you may find it insightful, so I will ride the mark downs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about the symbol of a person sitting or kneeling on the floor with a circle above their head? Or just their hands praying.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The Unitarian Universalists adopted a symbol of a flaming chalice. Modern UU is basically a covenantal religious practice of non- specific non-religion. Many are Atheist, Agnostic, Humanist, ethnically Jewish, Catholic, Muslim, Pagan, you name it, they only have to agree to 7 principals that basically amount to respect and kindness practices.

[image: Flaming Chalice]

Comment: I think your question was downvoted because you draw on a symbol that is already used by a particular group.